# Адаптер в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview

В общем создал BottomNavigationBar Activity. В нем еще два фрагмента разделенная через Tabbed menu. В каждой из них должен быть RecyclerView. Первая(Active) должна содержать в себе лист с Активными элементами, вторая с Завершенными(Ended). Так вот хватит ли обеим одного Адаптера? Или к каждому RecyclerView нужен отдельный адаптер? Буду делить их по SQL наверное со строкой "Active-true/false". Правильно ли вообще так делать? На данный момент Active и Ended показывают один и тот же список через один адаптер.

Answer (score 0):

если я вас правильно понял то просто создайте разные экземпляры адаптера для разных RecyclerView
например

```
 RecyclerAdapter active = new RecyclerAdapter();
 RecyclerAdapter ended = new RecyclerAdapter();
```